# I am using react-tinymce and its onChange prop is not working properly, it only call on few events, I want to call it on onKeyup event

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am building a React project, for some reason I am using **react-tinymce**, but it is not working properly, I want to get latest content from its onChange prop, please help, how to get the latest content on onKeyup event.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TinyMCE from 'react-tinymce';

const App = React.createClass({
  handleEditorChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getContent());
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <TinyMCE
        content="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
        config={{
          plugins: 'autolink link image lists print preview',
          toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright'
        }}
        onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
      />
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please share the code you're using?

Comment: Please check, I have uploaded the code

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE has a large set of events you can use to interact with the editor.  They are documented here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/

If you want to get notified on every key press there are key-related events you can use.  The onChange event does not trigger on every key press for performance reasons.

The documentation for the React/TinyMCE integration provides an example of how you can use these events:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#eventbinding

```
<Editor onKeyDown={this.handlerFunction} />
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has onEditorChange event so you can use this like following:

```
<Editor
   onEditorChange={handleChange}
   ...
/>


...


const handleChange = (content, editor) => {
   console.log(content);
}
```

It will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using useState hook for one of my projects. Here's the code I'm using to get the current text value from tiny mce editor. Hope you'll get it helpful.
<Editor
***onEditorChange={(content, editor) => {setBody(content)}}***
...

> 

Hope you'll find it helpful.